# Apply function using multiple values in rows

Tags: r

So far I've seen applying functions with two arguments and using the column index number. IS there a better way than using arguments but apply the entire column name? 
I have a table with multiple columns and each column value is used.

My actual df is larger than this and has a more complex function. So Im looking to pass the entire df names and not like this  `apply(df,c['price','quantity','level'],MARGIN=1, FUN= myfunc)`

```
df= data.frame(price = c(204, 45, 62),
                    type = c("F", "F","M"),
                    quantity = c(400,33,2),
                    level = c(1,3,1)
)
```

I'm looking for something where I do this:

```
myfun = function(){
   //uses every data row in the dataframe; without rewriting df all the time
   if (df$type == "F")
      return (df$price*df$quantity*df$level)
}
```

`apply(df, FUN = myfunc)`

Comment: ```Reduce(`*`, df[df$type == "F", -2])``` maybe

Comment: or with `library(dplyr)` this may work: `df %>% filter(type == "F") %>%  transmutate(return_value = price*quantity*level)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

```
res = apply(df, 1, function(t){
    if(t["type"] == "F") 
        return(as.numeric(t["price"]) * as.numeric(t["quantity"]) * as.numeric(t["level"]))
    else
        return("NO")
})
```

I hope this can solve your problem.